# How did the Joker's "pencil trick" kill his victim?

Tags: dc, batman

Is it stated somewhere if it was supposed to be a normal pencil? Not getting how that would be at all feasible to kill someone. Yes, I know it could, but the odds are so great as to defy suspension of disbelief.

Comment: You are supposed to suspend **belief**, not disbelief.

Comment: No, the term is "suspension of disbelief". Please look it up. Actually, I'll save you the trouble:Suspension of disbelief or willing suspension of disbelief is a term coined in 1817 by the poet and aesthetic philosopher Samuel Taylor Coleridge, who suggested that if a writer could infuse a "human interest and a semblance of truth"into a fantastic tale, the reader would suspend judgement concerning the implausibility of the narrative.Suspension of disbelief often applies to fictional works of the action, comedy, fantasy, and horror genres."Always wonder why people who are wrong need to comment.

Comment: “Is it stated somewhere if it was supposed to be a normal pencil?” — Would it make a difference if it were a... magic pencil?

Comment: if you want to analyze the scene you might be more curious about why the mobsters have cardboard top tables, that allowed the Joker to bury the entire tip of the pencil into the surface.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Batman has Kryptonite and magic thermonuclear energy generator. I can't see Joker NOT being allowed a magic pencil in the same universe.

Comment: Full answer below, but for the record, I was mentioning brain trauma, not brain damage.

Comment: Too bad it's on hold, because we've had a similar case in the Netherlands, the _[Leiden Biro Murder](http://www.volkskrant.nl/vk/nl/2844/Archief/archief/article/detail/433681/1996/02/20/Perfecte-moord-of-bizar-ongeluk.dhtml)_. Would've been a good starting point for an answer, although Dacio and beichst did a great job. There is even a book about this type of injury: _[The Transorbital Intracranial Penetrating Injury](http://books.google.be/books?id=7qAynwEACAAJ)_.

Comment: @Gelfamat: “Not getting how that would be at all feasible to kill someone.” Could you explain why it’s not feasible? To people not intimately familiar with brain traumas (which, I’m guessing, accounts for a large majority of the audience), I don’t think it’s obvious that this wouldn’t be fatal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ostensible reason the pencil was able to kill the victim was that it penetrated through the eye socket into the brain. However, while a great movie trick, from reviewing some of the medical cases which have occurred with this type of injury, this would appear to be unlikely to replicate in real life. This is due both to how the orbital socket of the eye is arranged as well as the eye itself acting as both a barrier and deflectant. Too, even if a person were to suffer such a puncture, it appears it would would probably not kill the person instaneously, but more slowly through blood loss and brain hemorrhaging. "Slowly" in this case being a matter of minutes, but not seconds.

In the attached article, we can see a pencil rammed almost exactly straight through the eye of the toddler, just like we would expect to see happen with the Joker trick. Yet, even so, the pencil is still sticking out. Too, though miraculous in surviving, as the article notes, had the infant died, it would be from blood loss through puncturing the blood vessels. Not the instaneous death we saw in the movie.

[Pencil in eye injury](http://article.wn.com/view/2012/07/04/Toddler_makes_full_recovery_after_pencil_pierced_eye_socket/)

[image]

In an incident in China, we see a scissors cause a similar issue.

[China infant scissors in eye](http://www.ndtv.com/article/world/chinese-toddler-survives-after-scissors-pierce-his-eye-socket-402096)

If we look at the seven bones making up the eye socket, we can see (no pun intended) how narrow the passage back to the brain via the optic nerve is. To be able to forcibly ram a pencil with such precision against an unwilling (though unsuspecting) victim would seem to be very unlikely.

[image: Eye Socket Bones 1]

[image: Eye Socket Bones 2]

Comment: Oh man, and that is exactly why I didn't search for images. Good info on the eye socket & skull bones, seems like my answer inflates the lethality of the injury.

Comment: Welp. No sleeping tonight.

Comment: “Not the instantaneous death we saw in the movie.” Are you sure that’s what you saw? It *is* a magic trick, after all. Could the impact of his head on the table have knocked him out cold, thus silencing him whilst the Joker makes his offer and leaves?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this question is poorly suited to the Science Fiction & Fantasy site because you are asking about facts of reality in the context of a fictional work. To be explicit about it, there are a number of ways a pencil to the brain could kill a person.

Since it is a work of fiction, I think we at least have to take it at *ahem* face value that the pencil did penetrate through the victims eye. If you are asking about whether or not it's possible to puncture a human eye with the blunt end of a pencil, then I humbly suggest a Fiction & Fantasy Q&A site is the wrong venue.

To business: While there is such a thing as a [transorbital lobotomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobotomy#Transorbital_lobotomy) (literally removing part of the brain through the eye socket) that patients presumably survive all the time, the procedure is done with surgical instruments on an immobile patient. I'm sure that, as with any surgical procedure, the mortality rate is greater than 0%. A traumatic puncture of the eye and brain, at high speed, with a blunt instrument (the eraser end) is sure to be much more lethal.

Consider a [.22 caliber bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobotomy#Transorbital_lobotomy) is 5.7 mm wide, weighs between 2 and 3 grams and has a kinetic energy between 140 and 300 Joules. Would you find it unbelievable if the Joker had killed a man by shooting him in the eye with a small pistol?

A #2 pencil, on the other hand, is over 7 inches long, 7mm wide and weighs between 6 and 8 grams. (I don't have a single authoritative source for these figures, just some googling. If you find different figures, well, the conclusions I'm about to draw should hold true for anything on the same order of magnitude.) From the footage, we can surmise that the pencil penetrated for *most*, if not all, of its length into the henchmans face. I don't have a figure for the average size of an adult, African-American skull, but: hold a pencil up to your head to see how far into your brain 7 inches would really penetrate.

Comparing the kinetic energy, a [punch can feasibly contain 100-450 Joules](http://www.science.ca/askascientist/viewquestion.php?qID=821) of energy. Put a pencil in that fist, and lethal damage is conceivable as you've over-topped the ballistic and kinetic profile of a small caliber bullet. You could argue that a criminal henchman would not allow someone to move their head and shoulders with that degree of force, and you might be right. But the Joker clearly did get the drop on Gambol's man; that noggin hits the table *hard*.

If ordinary brain trauma isn't enough to convince you of the lethality, also consider that there are [two arteries](http://www.innerbody.com/anatomy/cardiovascular/head-neck) behind your eyeballs. Any artery puncture can cause you to bleed out in minutes. Additionally, the human brain is a nest of blood vessels, both veins and arteries. You've probably heard of a [stroke](http://www.strokecenter.org/professionals/brain-anatomy/blood-vessels-of-the-brain/) and an [aneurysm](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/001414.htm); both of those are caused by irregularities of the brains blood supply and both can be lethal if unattended to.

Maybe the henchman was only stunned or knocked unconscious by the bump on the head and could have survived. For whatever reason, though, he goes down and doesn't get back up and the rest of the gangsters leave him lying on the floor at least until the end of the scene. So maybe Gambol actually blames himself for his boy's death, and is redirecting that anger onto the Joker...

So, not to answer a question with a question, but what do you find so unbelievable about that?

Comment: P.S. Dear federal government monitoring agencies, contrary to what my search history suggests, I am not actually interested in murdering people with icepicks *OR* pencils. I assure you my interest is purely hypothetical.

Comment: See the previous answer. Your assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: @Gelfamat Perhaps. But you also asked "How did [it] kill him?" which I think I covered pretty thoroughly. As for the realism, you might as well ask "How did the Joker plant so many bombs?" or "How does Wayne Enterprises get everyone in Gotham to replace their cell phones in just a few months?" or even "Why are there so many crime lords in Gotham?"

Comment: Let's deal with the question I did ask, not the random questions you speculate I might have asked.

Comment: @Gelfamat Uh.. okay. "How did the Joker's “pencil trick” kill his victim?" As for the other questions, I was merely contrasting that death-by-pencil is feasible, if not exactly plausible, unlike many other things in the trilogy.